# Can a solution of neem oil and water remain effective through storage, and if so, for apx. how long?

Tags: indoors, pesticide, storage

I made a mix of 1:8oz neem oil: water solution to treat some indoor plants against insects occassionally. I wonder how long, if at all, this solution can be stored and remain effective? It's in a sealed bucket stored indoors and I'm thinking I can mix it well before use and simply continue to use it as long as it lasts, but I wasn't able to find info on whether or not the solution will loose its effectiveness being stored like this over time (and if so, over what timespan).

Comment: It is stored in the dark (a bucket with a sealed cover over it) so light is not an issue. It is already mixed with water, and the bucket was not sterile, so microbes could be an issue.

Comment: Banned - wow! I didn't know that. I thought it was a fairly safe option, and occurring naturally makes me more confident it won't have unintended consequences. Apparently the EU disagrees - I'll have to look into why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to this substance, and have only used it once so far, after finding out it's a great solution to my current [black cherry aphid (aka cherry blackfly)](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=488) problem, but all of the information I have found so far says to **make a fresh batch each time, and use within a few hours.**

Here'a quote from [www.discoverneem.com](https://www.discoverneem.com/neem-insect-spray.html):

> Use your neem insect spray as quickly as possible, definitely within
>   eight hours. Once mixed with water the neem oil starts breaking down.
>   Always make a fresh batch for spraying, and only prepare the amount
>   you need.